# How to send data in PUT method using PEAR PHP Http_Request2 Library

Tags: php, web-services, rest, pear, http-put

I'm using the PEAR library Http_Request2.  I've been unsuccessfully searching for documentation on how to make a PUT request and pass parameters to a webservice.   Can anyone provide some help?

For a POST request, it's easy:

```
 $request = new HTTP_Request2 ( "http://my.url.com");
 $request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST);
 $request->addPostParameter('data', "blah"); //easy to add post params...
 $response = $request->send();
```

However, I can't figure how to send data when changing the method to PUT:

```
 $request = new HTTP_Request2 ( "http://my.url.com");
 $request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_PUT);

 // ?????  missing secret sauce to add data to put request....

 $response = $request->send();
```

Anyone lend a hand?

Comment: @wes thanks for the catch... fixed the typo.  No, can't use CURL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `setBody()` to set your PUT data. Don't forget the header, e.g.

```
$request->setHeader('Content-type: application/json');
$request->setBody('{"foo":"bar"}');
$response = $request->send();
```